# Click on any hyperlink or any content Chrome open a new link with a popup from?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome is my default browser. My problem is when I click page any content/hyperlink it’s open a new popup window and redirect my page on another ad-page.

I already install Ad-Block extension,but it’s not solve my problem.
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your addons and or plugins and disable everything you don't need!
The restart your browser and see if it still happens

```
chrome://extensions/
chrome://plugins/
```